# Let $f$ a measurable function, then $kf$ is a measurable function with $k\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ a measurable function, then $k.f$ is a measurable function with $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{A}$ a sigma-algebra of sets.

**My attempt**
Suppose $k>0$

$x\in (k.f)^{-1}((\ c,\infty\ ))\iff k.f(x)>c \iff f(x)>\frac{c}{k}$

As $f$ is a measurable function then for all $\alpha=c/k\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $f^{-1}((\ a,\infty\ )\in \mathbb{A}$ this implies $\{x:f(x)>\alpha\}\in\mathbb{A}$

Then
$(k.f)^{-1}((\ c,\infty\ ))\in\mathbb{A}$

In consequence, $k.f$ is a measurable function.

For the other cases is analogous. is correct this?

Comment: You don't need to assume $k > 0$.

Comment: okay, i understand. my other argument is okay? @IAmNoOne

Comment: I think it looks fine to me

Comment: $(kf)^{-1}(c, \infty)=f^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{k}, \infty \right)$ for $k > 0.$